# Can anyone identify the regiment and rank from this WWI photograph?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, britain, uniform, scotland

I am trying to identify the person in this WWI era photograph. I believe it may be my great great uncle John Hunt Marshall born Dec 29 1893 in Motherwell, Scotland. He graduated with a BSc from the University of Glasgow in 1913 and after the war was an engineering draftsman. I am not certain that this is him, however.

As such, is anyone able to identify the rank and regiment from the cap and lapel badges in the photograph taken at Romney, 534 Sauchiehall St, Glasgow?

[image]

Comment: Not he (almost certainly), but enough similarities to be of possible interest. 
https://universitystory.gla.ac.uk/ww1-biography/?id=2315 | University of Glasgow ... Engineering degree. ... passed his exams in Mathematics, Physics and Chemistry in 1913 and volunteered for service, ... temporary 2nd Lieutenant in the Highland Light Infantry. ... later transferred to the Regular Army, entering Woolwich Military Academy ... became a 2nd Lieutenant in the Royal Field Artillery. ... death at the Battle of Passchendaele on 22nd October 1917. A shell landed on his battery position

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I agree with Kobunite, but by a different route. I can't make out the cap badge well enough to identify it positively, but the collar badges are either Royal Artillery or Royal Engineers, which are quite similar. The cap badge definitely *isn't* Royal Artillery, which looks like this:

[image: Royal Artillery cap badge]

So he's Royal Engineers. The uniform is that of a commissioned officer: the diagonal strap is part of a "[Sam Browne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Browne_belt#United_Kingdom_and_the_Commonwealth)" belt, which were only worn by officers in the British Army.

The rank insignia would be on the jacket sleeves (until 1920), and we can't see them. Several things indicate the subject is likely a newly-commissioned officer, including his age, the poor fit of the uniform around the shoulders showing that it is not tailored for him, and the lack of any decorations or campaign ribbons. So he's probably a Second Lieutenant, the starting rank for officers. The style of the photograph looks like the ones that soldiers often had taken to send to relatives, but that's an impression, rather than hard fact.

It's very plausible that any one with a B.Sc. in an engineering-related subject would be commissioned in the Royal Engineers during WWI.

Comment: Thank you kindly

Comment: Until around 1920, most officers' rank badges were worn on the sleeves, not the shoulders.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If that's so, what *is* this person carrying on his shoulders? It definitely looks like a slip-on for rank.

Comment: A lot of [collar pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collar_pin) look like safety pins, but are really elaborate, purpose made; and pricey. Seems to me that making this the base for the conclusions is unfounded (although the assertions following  might still be true?)

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Removed that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Gotta agree with Mast that there is some kind of addition to his epaulettes. The angle of the photo makes it impossible to see what exactly.

Answer (score 13):

Starting with the regiment - looking at the cap badge (see below), I believe that he was in the Corps of Royal Engineers.

[image: https://www.iwm.org.uk/history/military-uniform-badges-and-portrait-photographs]

The uniform appears to be that of a commissioned officer, however the exact rank will be difficult as the British Army wears rank insignia on the shoulder boards and sleeves.

Comment: To me the lapel badge looks a bit like a fuisilier's badge, or a grenadier's badge.  Interpreting the blob on top as a bunch of flames instead of a crown.

Comment: @kimchilover  Both Engineers and Artillery wear a very similar bomb (in various locations) and also share the same motto: "Ubique".

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with Royal Engineers. The lapel badge of the Royal Fusiliers, although similar to the RE, is more "splayed - eg

[image]!

Comment: Hm. I am unconvinced [Royal Highland Fusiliers](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c2/e9/b8/c2e9b8dfbfd20c0257c455dcb9df9f04.gif) doesn't look that splayed,and given the src-material above, I#d not rule out [Royal Military police](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-zkbvw/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/4157/5307/Cap_badges__32591.1363883537.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on) either (given the appropriate version from the timeline; is the above WW1-era replica)? There is this strange triple thing I see to the left of what all sem to ID as a curved letter part?

Comment: WHat's missing from arguments is that there is [a banner below the lapel pins](https://www.alamy.com/photograph-taken-on-1st-april-1915-lieutenant-r-n-aylward-of-the-royal-engineers-of-the-british-army-taken-in-the-famous-bassano-photography-studio-in-london-first-world-war-soldier-image230194983.html), [and only that would make a match in my eyes](http://ww1photos.com/Names/G/GillFECaptainRE.html)